# Hyper-V VM Resolution Issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp, hyper-v, virtual-machines, screen-resolution

I created a Hyper-V VM on my Windows Server 2008 Standard machine.  On The VM I loaded Windows XP Home with SP3 from the MSDN ISO.  Everything works perfectly until I attempt to change the VM resolution from 800x600 to something larger like 1024x768 or 1920x1200.  The symptoms are that the screen turns black and the VM bounces in resolution back and forth between the 800x600 and whatever resolution I set it at.  When I set the resolution back (by waiting the 15 seconds without confirming), the problem stays.  After shutting down the VM and restarting, the problem still exists, even if I didn't save any settings!

I assumed it was the VM Installation so I removed it and re-installed and it was fine until I attempted to change the resolution.

here is an example of the symptoms: http://screencast.com/t/370hzAlwY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would load SP2 of Windows Server 2008 if you haven't, and also ensure that your Hyper-V has the latest patch. Then start with a clean install and install the Integration Tools. This looks to me like an Integrations Tools issue, which they hopefully fixed in a Win2k8 or Hyper-V patch.

Comment: I have the latest updates installed on my windows 2008 server (SP2) I check windows update and there are no updates available.  The first thing I do when installing the VM is install the integration tools.  Is there a patch for the Hyper-V or Integration tools that I should be aware of?

Comment: Sorry meant SP2 above (fixed). I checked and I don't see a patch that would fix this behavior: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd430893(WS.10).aspx (list of hotfixes).

A workaround is you could install XP Pro and use Remote Desktop to access the box. In fact, XP Pro might work a little better, so maybe you could have better luck with that.